The comment upvote arrow is not working during review; instead of voting, it scrolls up the page
When doing reviews, there are options. The last option, Other action, is grayed out until you do something, like comment or upvote a comment. I'm just mentioning this so we are on the same page.

I noticed that during review, when you try to click the upvote button for a comment, it doesn't always work. Most of the time, the page scrolls up when clicking it. I have noticed this behavior for a month now. Is anyone fixing this or aware of this bug? The workaround is to refresh the page, then it works.


I was here thinking I was the only one, or my browser was acting up, but I guess not, I've been having the same issue for a while now. I'm hoping that selling us off to AI is generating enough funds to develop and improve the platform

On topic of the issue itself, I've noticed that refreshing the review page makes the button work properly on second load

Yes that's the workaround I currently employ when I need to upvote a comment, just refresh the page haha

There seem to have been some recent development, now I get an error message saying something like I "cannot mark the same comment more than once" or similar, and the comment vote doesn't immediately show up. It still doesn't work properly, I have to then refresh the page to see my vote, but at least it no longer scrolls up

Just happened to me outside of the review - I edited a comment, then clicked the up arrow to upvote - the arrow activated but the score didn't update. Had to refresh the page and press the up arrow again...
